# How do I get Google ID Token on postman?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, postman, google-oauth, openid-connect

By setting `Authorizattion Code` as Grant Type, Im able to get access token in Postman. However the actual thing im looking for is ID token. Does anyone know how to get the Google ID Token from postman? I want to use this ID token to authenticate with a backend server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id token is used for Open Id connect or signin.

All you need in order to get an Id token is to pass the scope of profile then google will return an id token

```
{
  "access_token": "[Redacted]", 
  "id_token": "[Redacted]", 
  "expires_in": 3599, 
  "token_type": "Bearer", 
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", 
  "refresh_token": "[Redacted]"
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D This worked. I was using a different scope. That was the problem.